# loading image during ajaxmethod

Tags: jquery, ajax

Currently i am using following code to display results. When results contains many records from mysql (e.g. 5000 members or greater n following example), it takes some time to load data. I want to show loading image (path/images/loading.gif) during this process till displaying full data.

code is as follows :

```
 <select id="lifemember" name="lifemember">
                <option value="">Select Your Option</option>
               <option value="10">Last 10 Members</option>
               <option value="50">Last 50 Members</option>
               <option value="100">Last 100 Members</option>
               <option value="250">Last 250 Members</option>
               <option value="500">Last 500 Members</option>
               <option value="1000">Last 1000 Members</option>
               <option value="5000">Last 5000 Members</option>
               <option value="all">Show All Life Members List</option>
                </select>
               <div id='loader1' width="40px" align="left" style="width:40px; display:inline; float:left;"><img src="mysite.com/images/loading1.gif" /></div> <br>
```

And ajax code is as follows :

```
 <script>
  $('[name="lifemember"]').on('change', function() {

    var ajaxMethod = "default.php";

    switch($(this).val())

     {

      case "10":
        ajaxMethod = "members10.php";
      break;
      case "50":
        ajaxMethod = "members50.php";
      break;                
      case "100":
        ajaxMethod = "members100.php";
      break;        
      case "250":
        ajaxMethod = "members250.php";
      break;                 
      case "500":
        ajaxMethod = "members500.php";
      break;  
      case "1000":
        ajaxMethod = "members1000.php";
      break;   
      case "5000":
        ajaxMethod = "members5000.php";
      break;   
      case "all":
        ajaxMethod = "membersall.php";
      break;       
    }

         $("#results").load(ajaxMethod);

     });
   </script>
```

And Result is displayed in following division

```
<div id="results">LIFE MEMBERS LIST Will Be Shown Here After Selecting Your Option From Above Combobox...</div>
```

I want to show loading image (path/images/loading.gif) next to combobox.

Comment: Why negative Vote, ????

Comment: What is the `b` for in you selector ?

Comment: sorry, it is typo mistake.....edting it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just show the loader before the `load()` method, and hide it when data has been loaded :

```
$('[name="lifemember"]').on('change', function() {
    var ajaxMethod = "default.php";
    // ...
    $('#loader1 img').show();
    $("#results").load(ajaxMethod, function(){
        // on complete, hide the loader
        $('#loader1 img').hide();
    });
});
```